# Phonegap is taking too long to load..I'm afraid it's no longer normal

Tags: android, cordova

I'm new to phonegap and I tried their getting started [tutorial for android](http://phonegap.com/start#android) now I'm trying to run it on the emulator and here is what I get.

```
[2011-11-11 02:58:44 - SillyApp] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-11-11 02:58:44 - SillyApp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-11-11 02:59:11 - SillyApp] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-11-11 02:59:11 - SillyApp] Uploading SillyApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-11-11 02:59:11 - SillyApp] Installing SillyApp.apk...
```

And then the party stops there and nothing popped out of the emulator. It's been like that for  forever.. Is that normal? :(

Comment: @_@ I should stop making apps at 4am in the morning.. This kind of stuff is supposed to be basic.. lol.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unlock the emulator. Slide the green button to the right.

Comment: hmm.. but it went directly to the last snapshot.. must be something fishy.